# Break out while loop

Tags: c

Here's the main function where 9 more functions are called. I will show you another function in order to understand what my aim is.

```
int main() {
    char B[rows][columns];
    char answer;
    int newgame;
    printf("Are you ready to play? Answer with y (or Y) for yes or n (or N) for no\n");
    scanf("\n%c",&answer);
    while(answer!='N' && answer!='n'){
        fillArray(B);
        printArray(B);
        answer='y';
        while(answer!='N' && answer!='n'){
            vasilhs(B);
            printArray(B);
            check_draw(B);//I will place an if statement after the check_draw function
            check_vertical_win(B);
            check_horizontal_win(B);
            check_right_diagonal_win(B);
            check_left_diagonal_win(B);
            antipalos_paikths(B);
            printArray(B);
            check_draw(B);
            check_vertical_win(B);
            check_horizontal_win(B);
            check_right_diagonal_win(B);
            check_left_diagonal_win(B);
        }
        printf("Do you want to play again?\n");
        scanf("\n\n%c",&answer);
    }
    }//end of main function
    //function check_draw

    void check_draw(char A[rows][columns]){
    int i,j;
    int newgame;
    //if statement will check in an matrix if the following elements are equal to '-'
    if(A[0][0]!='-' && A[0][1]!='-' && A[0][2]!='-' && A[0][3]!='-' && A[0][4]!='-' && A[0][5]!='-' && A[0][6]!='-'){
        printf("The result is a draw");
        newgame=10;
    }
}
```

So when if statement in function check_draw is True the variable newgame gets the value 10.

```
if(newgame==10){
    break;
}
```

Why, when i place this if statement after the check_draw call ,doesn't it break the while loop?

Comment: You can't directly access local variables of one function in another!

Comment: Because `check_draw` has it's _own_ copy of `newgame`, distinct from the one in main. You'd be better having `check_draw` (and the other similar functions) returning a true/false (1/0) value and doing `if (checkDraw(B)) break ;` in main.

Comment: Where are `rows` and `columns` defined?

Comment: @Marievi they are defined in the beginning of the programme

Answer (score 0):

From your code implementation:

```
void check_draw(char A[rows][columns]){
    int i, j;
    int newgame;
    //if statement will check in an matrix if the following elements are equal to '-'
    if (A[0][0] != '-' && A[0][1] != '-' && A[0][2] != '-' && A[0][3] != '-' && A[0][4] != '-' && A[0][5] != '-' && A[0][6] != '-'){
        printf("The result is a draw");
        newgame = 10;
    }
}
```

`int newgame` here is local copy of `check_draw` function.

If another variable with same name exist as a global variable then you should not declare `int newgame` within `check_draw` function. It will make a local copy to work with.

Recommendation:

```
int newgame;// Write it outside main
void check_draw(char A[rows][columns]){
    int i, j;   
    //if statement will check in an matrix if the following elements are equal to '-'
    if (A[0][0] != '-' && A[0][1] != '-' && A[0][2] != '-' && A[0][3] != '-' && A[0][4] != '-' && A[0][5] != '-' && A[0][6] != '-'){
        printf("The result is a draw");
        newgame = 10;
    }
}
```

If you write `int newgame;` outside main and not making any local copy within `check_draw` function then `newgame = 10;` statement within `check_draw` function will change the value of global `newgame`.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `newgame` is defined *again* in function `check_draw`, so it is a ***local copy*** of `check_draw` which `main` *does not have access to*.

Supposing that variables `rows` and `columns` are correctly declared and initialized in a part of your code not shown here, one solution is to return `newgame`'s value to `main` and delete the declaration in 'main' :

```
int main() {
    char B[rows][columns];
    char answer;
    int result;
    printf("Are you ready to play? Answer with y (or Y) for yes or n (or N) for no\n");
    scanf("\n%c",&answer);
    while(answer!='N' && answer!='n'){
        fillArray(B);
        printArray(B);
        answer='y';
        while(answer!='N' && answer!='n'){
            result = check_draw(B);
        }
        printf("Do you want to play again?\n");
        scanf("\n\n%c",&answer);
    }
    }//end of main function
    //function check_draw

    int check_draw(char A[rows][columns]){
    int i,j;
    int newgame = -1;
    //if statement will check in an matrix if the following elements are equal to '-'
    if(A[0][0]!='-' && A[0][1]!='-' && A[0][2]!='-' && A[0][3]!='-' && A[0][4]!='-' && A[0][5]!='-' && A[0][6]!='-'){
        printf("The result is a draw");
        newgame=10;
    }
    return newgame;
}
```

Another solution would be to pass `main`'s variable `newgame` as a pointer and delete the declaration in `check_draw` :

```
int main() {
    char B[rows][columns];
    char answer;
    int newgame;
    printf("Are you ready to play? Answer with y (or Y) for yes or n (or N) for no\n");
    scanf("\n%c",&answer);
    while(answer!='N' && answer!='n'){
        fillArray(B);
        printArray(B);
        answer='y';
        while(answer!='N' && answer!='n'){
            check_draw(B, &newgame);
        }
        printf("Do you want to play again?\n");
        scanf("\n\n%c",&answer);
    }
    }//end of main function
    //function check_draw

    void check_draw(char A[rows][columns], int *newgame){
    int i,j;
    //if statement will check in an matrix if the following elements are equal to '-'
    if(A[0][0]!='-' && A[0][1]!='-' && A[0][2]!='-' && A[0][3]!='-' && A[0][4]!='-' && A[0][5]!='-' && A[0][6]!='-'){
        printf("The result is a draw");
        *newgame = 10;
    }
}
```

Please read [this link](https://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-functions-and-global-local-variables) on local variables' scope. Also take a look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm).